# Install proxy certificate to Java

Tags: java, proxy

I'm new to installing the certificates to Java. I've been asked to install a proxy certificate to Java. I couldn't find the best & I'm using windows machine for it. Can any one guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to authenticate you need the private key. There's no other option.

A certificate is a public key with extra properties (like company name, country,...) that is signed by some Certificate authority that guarantees that the attached properties are true.

.CER files are certificates and don't have the private key. The private key is provided with a .PFX keystore file normally. If you really authenticate is because you already had imported the private key.

You normally can import .CER certificates without any problems with

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"
```

Please have a look into [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html)   and also into [this one](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-java.htm)

Comment: Hi Syed,
Please go through the below link :
http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/2680.html#For_Windows

Comment: "-keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias" this is not required.